# Silently install JDK1.6 in shell script

Tags: shell, java, rpm

I'm trying to install JDK1.6 on a RHEL5.5 system in the %post section of the kickstart that uses shell commands. Though you need to accept the user agreement and accept that it will install some rpms and what not. Is there an easy way to do this? Or possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick:

```
export MORE=10000
sh thejdkbin.sh >/dev/null <<EOF
yes
EOF
```

(but by the way, why do you *install* a JDK in the `%post` section?)